# Gravatar are not showing up in android app

Tags: android, gravatar

Here is my code to display profile picture using gravatar.

```
ParseUser user = mUsers.get(position);
String email = user.getEmail().toLowerCase();

if (email.equals("")) {
    holder.userImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar_empty);
} else {
    String hash = MD5Util.md5Hex(email);
    String gravatarUrl = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" + hash + "?s=204&d=404";
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(gravatarUrl)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.avatar_empty)
            .into(holder.userImageView);
}
```

But it is not showing even my profile picture and loads empty drawable.

Comment: code form treehouse? It seems mine did't work either...

Comment: yes u got it..not working for me..

Comment: I posted a question in the forum, hopes someone can help:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used a bunch of fake emails to populate your friend list, if so, gravatar won't be able to find images for those fake emails. So gravatar will return a 404, and your code will use the default "avatar_empty" image in the `drawable` folder.

A quick way to test to see if gravatar is working is to `change the &d=404 to &d=monsterid` and `create a friend` with a fake email `"SDFSDSF@DSFSsdfsFSFSssf.com"`

That friend will `have an gravatar cartoon image.`

Also you can try put `http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/edb1260aa6f7f77688deee83e0a088f7?s=204&d=monsterid` in your `gravatarUrl`. It will show picture.

Comment: I have used all these things and now i understood that first i have to set up my profile image with corresponding email address in gravatar website then it will give your image. but i want to know one thing that gmail mails are valid not fake. now i am trying to upload profile pictures at the time of signup..

Comment: Good for you.. I should upload too.. If you feel my answer help, plz make as best answer, thx

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps someone ,   this is the code i used.
get library from:-   https://github.com/tkeunebr/gravatar-android  (you will get the .jar,,  add it to lib)

### Code for loading gravatar:

```
String gravatarUrl = Gravatar.init().with(user.email).size(100).build();
Picasso.with(mContext)
       .load(gravatarUrl)
       .into((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_avatar));
```

And if you want to set a default image in case of there is no gravatar set for the email(to override the default gravatar) then use:

```
String gravatarUrl = Gravatar.init().with(user.email).defaultImage(defaultImageUrl).size(100).build();
```

Hope this helps someone.